# I need to loop through the Sql table until a certain condition is met

Tags: sql, self-join

I am trying to find a supervisor ID of an employee based on the organization unit.

Table A: `Employee`

| EmpID | BeginDate | EndDate | OrgUnit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 20070618 | 20070624 | 5001 |

Table B: `OrgUnit`

| OrgType | OrgUnit | Code | Status | BeginDate | EndDate | SID |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O | 5001 | B | 008 | 20050101 | 20160619 | 4002 |  |
| O | 5001 | A | 002 | 20050101 | 20110201 | 4001 |  |
| O | 4001 | B | 008 | 20070618 | 20070624 | 4110 |  |
| O | 4001 | A | 002 | 20070618 | 20070624 | 4003 |  |
| O | 4003 | B | 012 | 20070618 | 20070624 | 4444 | - Supervisor ID |

- Step 1: Get the Org Unit from Table A for a `Emp ID = 1001`
- Step 2: Find a match for Org Unit in Table B and get SID for status B012
- Step 3: If the value does not exist in Step 2, check for the status, A 002,  get the new SID
- Step 4: If the value exists from Step 3, get new SID and for status B012 in the Table B  where OrgUnit = SID (from Step 3)
- Step 5: If value from Step 4 not exists, Search it for status A002 where OrgUnit = SID (Step 4) and get the new SID from table B
- Step 6: If value from Step 5 exists,Get new SID for status B 012 for OrgUnit = SID (from Step 5)
- Step 7: If value exists from step 6, get new SID for status 008 in Table B where OrgUnit = SID (from Step6)

**Note**: Steps 3, 4, 5 are kinda loop scenario until we have a SID for status B 012.

I am able to get the data for happy path. In case of data not found not sure how to match up SID against Table B for different code-status. I am trying not to have a cursor and loop through every record to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is somethat complicated, answer looks not so hard.

```
with o as (select orgunit, code||status code, sid from orgunit 
           where (code, status) in (('A', '002'), ('B', '012')) )
select o1.orgunit,
       case when o1.code = 'B012' then o1.sid
            when o1.code = 'A002' and o2.code = 'B012' then o2.sid
            when o1.code = 'A002' and o2.code = 'A002' and o3.code = 'B012' 
            then o3.sid
       end supervisor
from o o1
left join o o2 on o1.sid = o2.orgunit 
left join o o3 on o2.sid = o3.orgunit 
where o1.orgunit = (select orgunit from employee where empid = 1001)
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/pnbgg9iQ)

This solution is tested in Oracle platform, but is close to standard, except maybe concatenation, so you should be able translate it to any SQL dialect easily. I hope it will work, these are just three left joins and one `case`. In case you had unknown number of loops you would need recursive solution.

---

**Edit:** In your dbfiddle provided in comments you have the case, where employee has two paths:

```
ORGUNIT CODE    SID ORGUNIT CODE    SID 
2014    A002    120 120     A002    116   <-- not supervisor, null returned
2014    A002    120 120     B012    7733  <-- supervisor
```

In this case you can use simply min or max over `case` statement and group by orgunit [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/enl98cVJ).

But we can imagine, that second path leads to another supervisor:

```
ORGUNIT CODE    SID ORGUNIT CODE    SID ORGUNIT CODE    SID 
2014    A002    120 120     A002    116 116     B012    7775 <-- another  supervisor
2014    A002    120 120     B012    7733  <-- supervisor
```

If such situation is possible we have ambiguity and you have to decide what to do, it doesn't matter if you use something similar to my query or write procedure.

Comment: Maybe you can edit my [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pnbgg9iQ) and add some rows which allow us to reproduce wrog behavior? Otherwise it is really hard to guess what is going on. Simplified "loop" is done here by left joins.

Comment: Sure let me add some more records in your dbfiddle. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Click on dbfiddle link, add rows and click Run button, this generates new address, this is how dbfiddle works. Then post this link here or prefreably edit your initial question.

Comment: Hi @ponder-stibbons My apologies for getting back late. I updated your dbfiddle link and the results does show null. Can you please let me know how to adjust the query?

Comment: I do have unknown number of loops as I need to look until a supervisor ID is found.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/C7qbaSPQ

Comment: Here is my [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/C7qbaSPQ) with actual records and results

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance once again. This is somewhat complicated and really appreciate your help.